# Success Factors REST API OData Entity User does not return inactive users

Tags: sap-successfactors

Until 1,5 week ago, I was getting all user statuses from SuccessFactors OData User Entity via
REST GET

https://localhost:443/odata/v2/User

Now I noticed that inactive users  (where status  = 'f' )are not returned by this.

Does anyone have any information on this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an issue. Success Factors does not return inactive users if not told.

You have to add a filter if you want to get inactive users.

```
https://<hostname>/odata/v2/User?$filter=status in 'active','inactive'&$format=JSON
```

Here is list of statuses:

[list of statuses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPtoc.png)

Comment: So, I found SAP document 
2166571 - How to query inactive users on User entity - OData API
and it said 
https://<hostname>/odata/v2/User$filter=status in 'active','inactive'

Comment: SAP note: https://userapps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/2166571 state `&$filter=status in 't','f'`